# Are there any plans to have a bridge between the Cardano and Cosmos blockchains?

Tags: smart-contract, ethereum, defi

Are there any plans to have a bridge between the Cardano and Cosmos blockchains? Cosmos is working on the `gravity-bridge` which is a bridge between Ethereum and Cosmos so I assume there must be some emerging composability `Cardano <-> Eth <-> Cosmos` however the gas fees for this would be crazy.

Would Cardano's ERC20 converter let you go directly between Cardano and Cosmos because they both support ERC20 tokens?

Comment: Should one of the answers be marked as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

The Cosmos Blockchain and Atom token are not based on ERC-20, they support their transfer, so there is no prospect that the Cardano ERC-20 converter could be used directly.

No mention has been made of a Cardano-Cosmos bridge that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I believe every project is driven by a motive. ERC-20 converter makes sense because there are a lot of tokens that are struggling on ETH and would want to migrate. Sorry I have not done enough research on Cosmos. Although I like it based on what I know. But what would be a driving factor or a need for such a bridge between Cardano and Cosmos? May be that will help answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. The ERC-20 converter is meant only for ERC-20 tokens, which exist solely on the Ethereum blockchain.

I can only speak for myself here, but knowing how strongly the Cardano community believes in decentralization, I highly doubt there is any will within the Cardano community to create a bridge with a centralized blockchain ecosystem.

Binance smart chain, for example, has 21 (last I checked..) ***nodes in TOTAL***.

I do agree that there will be a "multi-chain future", but if a bridge were to be made it would likely be an effort on Cosmos behalf, not ours. I could be wrong however, if there is enough will to make it happen, anyone who knows plutus could design a smart contract to work as a bridge. However, I myself have zero interest in such a project as I am focused solely on Plutus dApps.

Comment: Cosmos is a framework that allows for decentralised blockchains. If I create a separate Cardano blockchain with a different network ID I could argue that's a centralised ecosystem too, as I control the only node.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a bridge, but I think we could benefit from one. As far as I know, there currently isn't a working decentralized hosting service on Cardano, like [Akash](https://akash.network/) on Cosmos. [NuNet](https://nunet.io/nunet-platfrom-alpha-and-showcase-application/) is in alpha, but I'm not sure when it'll be at the stage where Akash is presently.

I'm going to run into this issue later this year, while developing a decentralized no-code platform for building workflows. Should be fun